# Variables missing from vendors directory in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, vendor

I copied some lib files into the vendors directory of CakePHP. And used `App::import` to import the provided lib files.

I can initialize the Classes defined in the lib files, which means I've imported the files successfully. However, the global variables defined in the lib files cannot be used in the controller. As the notice says, the variables are undefined.

How would I access the variables in the lib files from the controller?

Comment: Most external libraries don't create true global variables - have you tried accessing them as static class variables? `MyClass::myVariable`

Comment: They are not defined under Class definition. They are defined directly at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Can you show some simple code that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Can you show the variables your trying to globally include, and give us a reason as to _why_ you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to just stick global variables into a file like that and trying to include them.

You should abstract the variables out to a class, or find a way around them all together.